# How do I point to a batch file using application.yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, batch-file, properties, yaml

I have a spring boot project that starts a batch file when I hard code the batch file location like below.

```
String path="cmd /c start C:/mybatchfile/Export.bat";
Runtime rn=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr=rn.exec(path);
```

Now I would like to pass this batch file from a yml configuration file.

```
@Value("${myproject.batchlocation}")
private String batchLocation;
String path="cmd /c start batchLocation";
```

When I print the value to screen

```
@Value("${myproject.batchlocation}")
private String batchLocation;
System.out.println(batchLocation)
```

it prints the string value

```
C:/mybatchfile/Export.bat
```

However, I get the following Windows error when i run the program.

windows cannot find batch location.  Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

How do I point to this batch file using application.yml file?
I've tried with ("/"forward) (back"\") and removing C:

Comment: How do you run a program, when you use injected property?

Comment: So you have your current code like this?
`String path="cmd /c start " + batchLocation;`

Comment: You should try with path: "C:\mybatchfile\Export.bat", using "\" instead of "/"

Comment: backslash didn't work either.